# Is it possible to update iPhone running iOS 13.5.1 to 13.7 not 14.4?

Tags: iphone, ios

On macOS, Apple pushes security updates to older versions such as Catalina... we don't have to upgrade to Big Sur.

Is the same possible on iOS? I am aware of recent zero day patches but would like to avoid upgrading to iOS 14.

According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393#137, I see many versions were pushed since `13.5.1`, but somehow, I can only upgrade to `14.4` on my iPhone SE (2020).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the way with iOS.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, NO.

After Apple stops signing an older build, there's no way to "easily, as a normal user" update to any other version than the newest.

Comment: What does "easily, as a normal user" mean? Is there any way at all, even if it's hard?

Comment: I've read of ways to set up your own server to spoof Apple's servers and change the signing or date, and have your phone connect to that server. But that's lots of work and knowledge, on the level or coder or advance jailbreaking. Not what I consider "average user skill".

Comment: I am a moderately advanced jailbreaker, and I have only been able to downgrade an iPhone 4s from 9.3.5, to 6.1.3.  I have tried on a newer device, but it just isn't feasible.  I found this, but I haven't tried it yet: https://github.com/marijuanARM/Inferius